# How do I call my own API from a View? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, api, model-view-controller, asp.net-apicontroller

I have an API that I've created for user registration / authentication, and similar operations. Example post method:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("authenticate")]
    public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]AuthenticateModel model)
    {
        var user = _userService.Authenticate(model.Username, model.Password);

        if (user == null)
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password is incorrect" });

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role)
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        // return basic user info and authentication token
        return Ok(new
        {
            user.Id,
            user.Username,
            Token = tokenString,

        });
```

I now need my front-end to implement my API. So I'd like to call this API from a View. For example, say I want to create a simple login page:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Username"></label>
            <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Password"></label>
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

How would I now call the authenticate post method for this login form? As I have a controller which is the API controller, and I have a controller which is the action controller, for the users.

File structure if needed:
[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB4x6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling your own web action can be done in mainly two ways:

- Native HTML form submission.
- AJAX

Native submit reloads your entire page. And address will be changed to the URL or your web action. Typically used as a search function, like:

```html
<form asp-controller="Search" asp-action="Blogs" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="question" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When the user submit the form with clicking the submit button, the browser will be redirect to `/search/blogs?question=textHeInput`.

To prevent page refreshing, you can submit a request with pure JavaScript. Which called AJAX.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

For example:

```js
// Require jQuery:
$.post('/authenticate', { "yourPropertyName" : "yourPropertyValue" }, function(response) {
    // Do something after the request. Access response like this:
    alert(response.Username);
});
```

And server responded username will shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.NET MVC Core Tag Helpers:

```html
<form asp-controller="MyControllerName" asp-action="Authenticate" method="post">
    <!-- Input and Submit elements -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `JwtBearer` with WebAPI's, an assumption is that you're probably going to call your authentication method using Ajax. Unfortunately you did not provide your class declaration showing your route convention for your ApiClass but normally it goes as `"api/[Controller]"`... If this is the case, you can do the following:

```js
$("submitButton").click( 
  function authenticateUser()
  {
    $.post(
      '/api/[COntrollerName]/authentication', // URL
      $('#form").serialize(), // this is your form data as an object
      function(payload) //Response 
      {
        // do something with payload here
      }
    });
  }
);
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton">Login</button>
```

You might want to set your `<button type="button">` so that the form doesn't submit. Attach a click event to that function, so that it processes the api call.